# In blackberry does android player supports push notifications or C2dm?

Tags: android, blackberry, android-c2dm, push-notification

I want to develop android application so that it also works on blackberry. I have searched that blackberry onward 10 and blackberry playbook supports android application and android player to run android applications. So in my application I'm using C2DM Push notifications from server so does this feature is supported by blackberry android player, if I make this in native android?
For the above scenario do I have to make application in native android and blackberry each or I can make for only android and it will run in blackberry with the C2DM feature?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android C2DM requires the presence of Google Play (formerly Android Market).  Without this component, your client won't be able to receive notifications.

Comment: Appreciated! Does blackberry android player have a silent listener so that I could push notification via it by my self?

Comment: Dunno, but you could write one. :-)  Here's my thinking on this: C2DM is, largely, a mechanism that allows the OS to pool all the messaging listeners together and activate the radio to receive messages for them all at once, saving battery.  Convenience for the developer is nice, but reducing power is critical.  But when you're running in a compatibility box like on Blackberry, these considerations become mostly irrelevant, because the OS you're trying to optimize isn't there.  If you know approximately how often to expect data, you'd do about as well to use an inexact repeating alarm.